# Remove objects from array by referencing another aray

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have an array called `new_svrgrp_member` like this -

```
new_svrgrp_member = [];
new_svrgrp_member.push({
    Member:"a25346j2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN001271"
},{
    Member:"m82298s2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN001271"
},{
    Member:"a25346j2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN000868"
},{
    Member:"a25346j2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN000901"
},{
    Member:"v38250s", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN000903"
},{
    Member:"a25346j2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN002085"
},{
    Member:"a25346j2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN001367"
},{
    Member:"v38250s", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN001367"
},{
    Member:"d76686g2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WNR00096"
},{
    Member:"s98681s2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WGR00006"
})
```

Then I have a `FilterMmbr` array like this -

```
FilterMmbr = [];
FilterMmbr.push({Name: "s98681s2"},{Name: "s98681s"},{Name: "v38250s"},{Name: "SI_VWAdmChk"})
```

I need to take out all objects from `new_svrgrp_member` which match `FilterMmbr's` `Name` property with `new_svrgrp_member's` `Member` property.

I used the following code to do that -

```
for each(Mmbr in FilterMmbr)
{
    var removeIndex = new_svrgrp_member.map(function (item) {
        return item.Member;
    }).indexOf(Mmbr.Name);
    ~removeIndex && new_svrgrp_member.splice(removeIndex, 1);
}
```

it removes the objects but with only one match, here is the output I get -

```
[INFO] New members after filtering...
[INFO] Member:a25346j2 MemberClass:user Parent:SVR_ADM_WN001271
[INFO] Member:m82298s2 MemberClass:user Parent:SVR_ADM_WN001271
[INFO] Member:a25346j2 MemberClass:user Parent:SVR_ADM_WN000868
[INFO] Member:a25346j2 MemberClass:user Parent:SVR_ADM_WN000901
[INFO] Member:a25346j2 MemberClass:user Parent:SVR_ADM_WN002085
[INFO] Member:a25346j2 MemberClass:user Parent:SVR_ADM_WN001367
[INFO] Member:v38250s MemberClass:user Parent:SVR_ADM_WN001367  //Still exists
[INFO] Member:d76686g2 MemberClass:user Parent:SVR_ADM_WNR00096
```

How do I get rid of all objects with matches and why is there still one object left?

Comment: Don't use `splice` in a loop. (Also, what is `for each`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to strip values out of `new_svrgrp_member` that match a name in `FilterMmbr` (found using [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)):

```js
let new_svrgrp_member = [];
new_svrgrp_member.push({
    Member:"a25346j2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN001271"
},{
    Member:"m82298s2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN001271"
},{
    Member:"a25346j2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN000868"
},{
    Member:"a25346j2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN000901"
},{
    Member:"v38250s", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN000903"
},{
    Member:"a25346j2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN002085"
},{
    Member:"a25346j2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN001367"
},{
    Member:"v38250s", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WN001367"
},{
    Member:"d76686g2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WNR00096"
},{
    Member:"s98681s2", MemberClass:"user", Parent:"SVR_ADM_WGR00006"
});

let FilterMmbr = [];
FilterMmbr.push({Name: "s98681s2"},{Name: "s98681s"},{Name: "v38250s"},{Name: "SI_VWAdmChk"});

new_svrgrp_member = new_svrgrp_member.filter(m => !FilterMmbr.some(f => f.Name == m.Member));
console.log(new_svrgrp_member);
```